# Android: Add connection to a contact in the people app

Tags: android

The question says it all,i want to know if its possible to add a custom connection to a contact in the people app

Any resources, references, links and source code is appreciated

regards

Comment: no one has an answer for this question??

Comment: I have also been looking for this info without much luck..

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a way to do this from the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html#SocialStreamInteraction). It is a feature for api level 14 and above.

Just read under the section : Interacting with your social networking service